# is there a php equivalent to javascripts a = b && b.c || d

Tags: php, javascript, variables

is there any way i can mimic javascripts loose variable handling in php?
for example, in php i have to write

```
$instituteID = ( isset( $p['regInstituteName'] ) && isset( $p['regInstituteName']['ID'] ) ) ? $p['regInstituteName']['ID'] : null;
```

whereas in javascript this would condense to

```
instituteID = p.regInstituteName && p.regInstituteName.id || null;
```

doesnt seem like THAT much of a difference but it adds up

Comment: There isn't. Your best bet is the condensed ternary operator `?:` to replace the lazy OR `||`.

Comment: In my personal opinion the best way is not to code such non trivial expressions. Please think about these pure guys who will try to understand your code in future.

Comment: Personally I would abstract this into a function that is used like this: `$institureId = ifDefined($p, 'regInstituteName.ID')`

Comment: @Deestan, i had a similar idea. but yours looks better thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically.. no. There [have been some proposals](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/ifsetor) in the past, but they have been rejected.

**Edit**: You can optimize it in the case you are happy throwing `E_NOTICE` errors. But I'd recommend against that.

Comment: What about condensed ternary?

Comment: Doesn't solve it. OP needs to do an `isset()` first, and the result of `isset($x) || $x` will result in a boolean.

Answer (score 2):

You only need one `isset` with your case.

Because if `$p['regInstituteName']['ID']` is set, then `$p['regInstituteName']` is always set.

```
$instituteID = isset($p['regInstituteName']['ID']) ? $p['regInstituteName']['ID'] : null;
```

Comment: didn know that. figured to take the sure road, but thanks for this hint